# PHP: Namespacing Third-party Modules / Plugins in your Current Framework

Tags: php, plugins, namespaces

Let's say I have framework called Foo and it contains the following namespaces:

1. `Foo\Controllers`
2. `Foo\Models`
3. `Foo\Core`

I want to include a third party plugin (Symfony YAML) but it's not a namespaced library.

How would I go about including all the YAML classes (there's four) into the following namespace:

`Foo\ThirdParty\YAML`

Without editing the original Symfony YAML files?

Comment: Do you have an actual identifier clash, or is the namespace wrapping an end in itself?

Comment: The namespace wrapping is an end to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without modifying the original files.  Even if you created namespaced wrapper classes that extended Symfony's YAML classes, the original ones would still reside in the global namespace (defeating the purpose of namespacing).

Is there a reason you don't want to modify the original files?  Namespacing is very easy to merge, if you're worried about having to update the Symfony packages (you *are* using version control, yes?).

Comment: The main reason for not wanting to modify the original files is because YAML is being included as a submodule via git.

Comment: Why not put it in your own repo and make the modifications?  Then you can merge in YAML updates as needed (not very often, if ever) and it will be namespaced.